# How to hold single point plots in python?

Tags: python, pythonplotter

Is there any way to hold all the plots together (every plot is a point) in the following code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

g=10.7247;

x0=0;
z0=30;

v0=100*0.4889;
theta=np.pi/5;

vx=v0*np.cos(theta);
vz=v0*np.sin(theta);

for t in np.arange(0,10,0.1):
    x=x0+vx*t;
    z=z0+vz*t-1/2*g*t**2;
    plt.scatter(x,z)
    plt.xlim(0,300)
    plt.ylim(0,100)
    plt.pause(0.01)
    if z<0:
        break;

plt.show()
```

I used the plt.plot because I want the points to present one after the other but without any hold feature it returns a moving point. I want it to be like an animation. Every point should appear after 0.01s.

Here is exactly what I want: https://youtu.be/CK7Zq0kGiLY

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Welcome to SO! Would you please elaborate a bit more what you're asking for?

Comment: What does it means "to hold all the plots together"?

Comment: So the problem is that the points appear slower than 0.01s. Is that it?

Comment: @lepsch no the problem is that it is appeared one point moving.

Comment: Here is exactly what I want: https://youtu.be/CK7Zq0kGiLY